# Project like Trello, create a suitable database in Mongoose

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to create project like Trello. Could someone tell me how to create a database for a card because I first figured out that to the list model I add a field:

```
card: { type: Array },
```

And now the question is whether it will be okay. Because I think that by operating on the board I will be easier to set cards in sequence. But later I want to add drag and drop with move card from one list to another.

And later on I want to add the option to add photos to the card and now the question is whether to do it as a model in the list or create a separate model card?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you create it with relational database? It's more suitable with this kind of use case.

Board table:

> - Id
> - BoardName
> - UserId (Belongs to which user?)

List table:

> - Id
> - BoardId (In which board?)

Card table:

> - Id
> - ListId (In which list?)
> - Content
> - Position (Later to enable drag & dropping)

See, you don't need NoSql :)

Comment: It's about using new tools, could I just as you say on MongoDB (Mongoose) and it will work?

Comment: Can you see here, continue the thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46174156/the-correct-way-to-display-cards-in-lists-as-in-trello