# The correct way to display cards in lists, as in Trello

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to create project like Trello. I do not know how to do it properly.

I created function init in AngularJS Controller where i put http requests:

```
    $scope.loadLists();
    $scope.loadsCards();
```

Scripts:

```
$scope.loadLists = function () {
    return ApiService.staff.list()
        .then(function (resp) {
            for (var i = 0; i < resp.length; i++) {
                $scope.lists[i] = resp[i];
            }
        })
}

$scope.loadsCards = function () {
    return ApiService.staff.cards()
        .then(function (resp) {
            for (var i = 0; i < resp.length; i++) {
                $scope.cards = resp;
            }
            console.log($scope.cards)
        })
}
```

I'm downloading tasks to $scope.cards

In `console.log()` we can see:

```
Array [ Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object ]
```

where the object consists of

```
var CardSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, maxlength: 20, required: true },
  list: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'List' },
  updated: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  created: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  active: Boolean
});
```

And now I do not know what to do so that the cards are displayed only those in the given column that are assigned to the list. I mean : `task.list == list._id`

for the moment I did it

```
  <div ng-repeat="list in lists track by $index">
    <div style="float: left; margin-left: 5px;">
      <div id="tasks">

        <h3>{{list.name}}</h3>{{$index}}

        <ul>
          <li ng-repeat="task in cards"> 

            <div ng-hide="task.list == list._id">
              {{task.name}}
            </div>

            <i ng-click="removeTask(task)" class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></li>
        </ul>

        <form ng-submit="addTask(list._id, $index, newTask)">
          <input type="text" ng-model="newTask" placeholder="add a new task" required />
        </form>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

But it does not work and so it probably can not be if I want to still create a database for the card field

> Position (Later to enable drag & dropping)

Can anyone tell me how to properly display cards in lists?

EDIT;;;

thank you very much for the help.

Can you explain more to me because I still have a problem with the cards

I did directiv in angularJS:

```
App.directive('myList', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        template: '<div style="float: left; margin-left: 5px;"><div id="tasks">{{list.name}}<br>{{card.name}}</div></div>'
    };
});

App.directive('myCard', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        template: '<div style="float: left; margin-left: 5px;"><div id="tasks">{{card.name}}</div></div>'
    };
});
```

and in index.ejs

```
<my-list ng-repeat="list in lists" list-data="list"></my-list>
<my-card ng-repeat="card in listData.cards" card-data="card"></my-card>
```

I also did AJAX inquiry after all cards :

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/ed17c3fd675ea4361cb8fbd78e94cb37

name: its name card
list: its _id list

In  $scope.cards I stores AJAX inquiry after all cards,

Its my card model

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;


var CardSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, maxlength: 20, required: true },
  // description: { type: String, maxlength: 300 },
  list: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'List' },
  updated: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  created: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  active: Boolean
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Card', CardSchema);
```

And I have no idea how this loop looks, would you help me somehow?

Answer (score 0):

It's not that easy to solve with two `ng-repeat`'s. You may want to create your `list` and `card` directives because eventually they will be complex views:

```
<my-list ng-repeat="list in lists" list-data="list"></my-list>
```

And **in** `my-list` directive, you can create a loop to to render cards:

```
<my-card ng-repeat="card in listData.cards" card-data="card"></my-card>
```

Comment: Hey you can look higher, sorry for my lack of knowledge